How to make use of meetingId found in sample 'hello-world-in-meeting' with MS Graph
I have been toying with sample https://github.com/OfficeDev/teams-toolkit-samples/tree/dev/hello-world-in-meeting.  While in the meeting, the app returns a Meeting ID that is apparently not what can be used with Microsoft Graph.
According to the below issues, this issue is evidently (and unfortunately) expected:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/issues/539
https://github.com/OfficeDev/teams-toolkit/issues/5243

They both recommend to use the getMeetingInfo function of the botbuilder SDK.  However, I have no idea how to utilize that since this app is not a BotFramework app (nor do I want it to be).
Is there a way to use the Teams Toolkit to retrieve the real (usable with MS Graph) meeting ID from context?
Expected the meetingId returned to be identical to the meeting ID used in Microsoft Graph endpoints.

This is a known disconnect. The meetingId exposed by the Teams Client SDK differs from the meeting id exposed in Graph. However, you should be able to get the Graph meeting id by making a call to

GET /chats/{chat-id}?$select=onlineMeetingInfo

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-get-the-meeting-details-of-a-chat-associated-with-a-microsoft-teams-meeting

Thereafter use the following request to get the OnlineMeeting resource:
GET /users/{userId}/onlineMeetings?$filter=joinWebUrl eq '{joinWebUrl}'


You would get the {chat-id} for #1 from a call into Teams Client SDK.
Response to #2 will give you the correct Graph OnlineMeetingId in case you want to store a mapping for later.

Thanks!  This will have to do until one of the SDK's makes this much easier.
